# Downvote frenzy on new questions

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Is there any possibility of implementing a rule that would prohibit downvoting of the new questions for a particular period of time, let's say a protection for 5-10min after the initial posting? Give the user some time to understand the comments made by the community and let him to improve the question? I just witnessed a question that was completely new (less than a minute) and already had -7! This is not very welcoming for new users.

Yes, I know that people should learn the rules before they ask a question, but hey, honestly, how many people really do that when visiting every new website and looking for help? I'm not saying, that we should ignore them and don't downvote at all. Downvoting is a mechanism that pretty much works, no dispute about that. What I am saying - give them a chance.

The question I'm talking about HAS BEEN improved because of the comments, but it already has 4 close votes and -10... Downvote ragers won't cancel their downvotes, because it's not what they do. They see a bad question and BAM. -1

And lastly, yes, I know that most people that will respond to this isn't probably are not like this I'm describing. I'm not asking YOU to stop that, because it's obvious that you care about this website and probably never done such thing. My question is this: Is there any chance of implementing a mechanism to prevent this offensive behavior that encourages many newcomers?

Comment: The problem is not being able to downvote so soon, but the lack of revisiting.

Comment: "Downvote ragers won't cancel their downvotes, because it's not what they do." ... ... ... "They see a bad question and BAM. -1" Incidentally, that's what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Link to the question ?

Comment: What about legitimate downvotes to really bad questions ? The same happened with this ["question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016380/please-help-me-with-c)

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby, one thing is to vote on question and the other that if you downvote a question, you shouldn't abandon it and run away. If you see a newcomer struggling with forming his question, your instincts shouldn't be "yeah, give him PAIN". Would you be still here if the community was like that when you first came here?

Comment: @walther: That question is *horrible*. It lacks even the most basic research the user could have done on it's own, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @AshRj, I don't have a problem with that. I have a problem with downvoting questions of newcomers before they get any chance of explaining. If you're here for a month let's say and post such question, hell I don't care. But it's very bad for the new people, that aren't familiar with the rules just yet and get -10 in the first minute after the registration.

Comment: @walther: Actually, it was. I did post quite a few bad answers in the beginning...the community downvoted those, I learned from it and wrote better ones. I can not comment on questions, though, my Google-Fu is very strong and I find nearly everything within 10 minutes. But yeah, RobW alrady mentioned that running away thingy.

Comment: @walther The [OP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2282693/marquis-watkins) in my linked question was new as well. First post.

Comment: @walther: Do you understand that before anyone gets to ask a question, they have to go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice and explicitly tick the box saying they've understood? It's not like this no advice has been given. The user has chosen to ignore advice that they've confirmed they've read.

Comment: You don't get it. This is only one example, but this is a wider-spread problem. I'm not talking only about this particular question, it's been common here for months. Some really interesting, yet kinda badly explained questions, were closed in a minute and consequently deleted altogether, because the user didn't want to have -10 to start with. People didn't care they improve, they cast a vote and run away. Don't judge my thoughts based on a single question I've posted as an example, I'm not perfect either nor can't bring from "death" those good questions that got deleted by the owners.

Comment: "But hey, honestly, how many people really do that when visiting every new website and looking for help?" And this is our problem because.....?

Comment: @walther You have presented only one side of a problem without at all looking at the opposing side. Hence, the widespread disagreement.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I do. However, what I do understand as well is that when you buy a license from Microsoft for Windows and start the setup, you're prompted with several licenses/rules windows explaining your rights, your obligations etc. Do you read them EVERY SINGLE TIME you install a new copy? It's the same with websites, if people were to read rules of every single site they visit, well, they wouldn't be doing anything else the whole day, I can guarantee you that. I'm not saying "don't downvote", I'm saying "explain and give them a minute to improve". If they ignore it, BASH THEM.

Comment: @walther: I don't read EULAs thoroughly, but I acknowledge that if I violate one *I'm* in the wrong. If I'm interacting with a website which explicitly takes me through an interstitial telling me how to interact well, I *do* read that, yes.

Comment: @walther: The analogy is incorrect, the correct one would be "do you read the license terms of every single software you buy and install?".

Comment: @walther: "This is only one example, but this is a wider-spread problem." We see this a lot - people give a bad example, but then insist that really there's a problem elsewhere. If this is such a common problem, you should be able to give a *good* example. There are plenty of closed-but-not-deleted questions - if you find examples where people haven't clearly been simply too lazy to do any research etc, provide those examples.

Comment: @AshRj, yep, -8 in 20 minutes, that's lovely. Downvoting should definitely be a new sport for the next Olympics, this community could easily own anyone else. Just a click away... :) I say "give them a chance to improve" and everyone bashes at me :))) `-8 for expressing my point of view. By which rules did this feature-request deserved it?` Just explain this for me and I'm on done here. Thank you.

Comment: @walther With regards to that, you might want to read the Meta FAQ. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @walther - [Voting is different on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) If you had read the Meta FAQ, you would have known that.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I don't archive every good question that got deleted by the owner, do you? I guess I should start doing that in case someone would ask me such question next time.

Comment: @walther: I don't, but then I'm not protesting them being downvoted, am I?

Comment: @walther It would make your case a whole lot stronger. In the face of evidence, it becomes hard to disagree with you. So if you have it, provide it. And if not, make sure you get it.

Comment: @Bart, like Terminator said when he was still a young robot, `I'll be back` :) I have a bad a feeling I overestimated the community, thinking they watch the situation more closely and I won't have to provide some extensive evidence as if I was facing a trial. :) Doesn't matter now, when I get it, I'll update the "question".

Comment: @walther: Before asking this question, did you look at all the related questions? It's not like this is the first time this issue has been discussed.

Comment: @walther Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. And that burden falls entirely on you. As you can see from the voting tooltips, even on Meta we require and appreciate research effort. Gut-feelings are nice, but they don't create anything constructive. That said, good luck. If you have something, by all means let us know. If there really is a significant problem, we'd love to know about it.

Comment: I have absolutely no sympathy for an example question asking about parameters in a PHP URL that's tagged C# and asp.net. C'mon.

Answer (score 7):

> They see a bad question and BAM. -1

The point of down-voting is spotting bad questions/answers and preventing Stack Exchange users to get bad informations from the sites.

That being said, I'm not sure there should be a way of limiting down-votes, since a lot of these questions deserve those votes. If the new user (we're talking about +- 20 Reputation) gets all those down-votes, the penalty is not that bad since he can only lose a limited amount of reputation which is just perfect.

Also, the community is mostly helpful with the user by posting comments like :

```
Welcome to Stack Overflow, please refer to the F.A.Q section to know how to ask questions that fits this site's standards
```

or

```
Can you provide more information? What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?
```

Limiting the down-voting system would be, in my opinion, a bad approach since bad reviews are the best motivation to try and make better questions.

Comment: Even though I can agree with most parts (as I've said in my question), I'm not talking about the situations when the person is obviously some lazy moron who asks questions like "how do you create a website?". I'm talking about situations, when the question could use just some minor polishing and be perfectly valid, but the community discourages the person so he better deletes his question altogether. I can't agree with your conclusion, that bad review gives the best motivation. It depends on the person. Some people really suffer under such conditions and maybe won't post ever again.

Comment: I guess you're right but in that case you won't be able to please everybody since not everyone will agree on that subject. Questions with minor problems will *usually* get minor downvotes. If they get too much, the question is actually not good enough and should be deleted... Again, *usually*

Comment: I agree with walther